# How to duplicate mouse cursor movement and clicks on windows?

Tags: windows, mouse, duplicate, cursor, broadcast

Basicly what I'm trying to achieve is when moving my mouse I want to have second cursor duplicating everything I'm doing with my mouse ideally on second monitor or at least in second window or maybe even on second pc.

Think about it like having two paints open and drawing the same thing on both of them with one mouse. 
 I'm also looking to achieve the same thing with keyboard. I checked some multiboxing software but they seem to be outdated and working poorly. Is there a software to make it work?

Comment: It's not clear for what purpose you would want to do this, but multiboxing software would be the apparent solution. Which ones have you tried and on what OS?

Comment: Maybe this?>>>>>>>>https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35460

Comment: This question gets asked in various forms every couple of months, but there's never a strong-enough answer to float it into 'easy search' territory. It's usually so someone can play the same game twice, or other such excuse, sock-puppetting some system or other.

Comment: @BrianZ The purpose is gaiming but the game is not the one multiboxing software target so I'm just looking for the functionality I described and I tried most of the popular software but didn't find what I was looking for

Comment: @Moab this just allows to switch between screens, not what I'm looking for but thanks

Comment: Using 2 pc's i'd look for a harware solution like: grab a bluetooth mouse & keyboard, connect them to both pc's and go. Might not work for all HW but for sure I have a mouse which DOES achieve that